# How to find first/second element of associative array when keys are unknown?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

In PHP when you have an associative array, e.g.:

```
$groups['paragraph'] = 3
$groups['line'] = 3
```

**what is the syntax to access the first or second element of the array when you don't know the value of the keys**?

Is there something like in a C# LINQ statement where you can say:

```
$mostFrequentGroup = $groups->first()?
```

or

```
$mostFrequentGroup = $groups->getElementWithIndex(0)?
```

Or do I have to use a foreach statement and pick them out as I do at the bottom of this code example:

```
//should return "paragraph"
echo getMostFrequentlyOccurringItem(array('line', 'paragraph', 'paragraph'));

//should return "line"
echo getMostFrequentlyOccurringItem(array('wholeNumber', 'date', 'date', 'line', 'line', 'line'));

//should return null
echo getMostFrequentlyOccurringItem(array('wholeNumber', 'wholeNumber', 'paragraph', 'paragraph'));

//should return "wholeNumber"
echo getMostFrequentlyOccurringItem(array('wholeNumber', '', '', ''));

function getMostFrequentlyOccurringItem($items) {

    //catch invalid entry
    if($items == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if(count($items) == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    //sort
    $groups = array_count_values($items);
    arsort($groups);

    //if there was a tie, then return null
    if($groups[0] == $groups[1]) { //******** HOW TO DO THIS? ***********
        return null;
    }

    //get most frequent
    $mostFrequentGroup = '';
    foreach($groups as $group => $numberOfTimesOccurrred) {
        if(trim($group) != '') {
            $mostFrequentGroup = $group;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $mostFrequentGroup;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use these functions to set the internal array pointer:

http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

And this one to get the actual element:
http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

```
reset($groups);
echo current($groups); //the first one
end($groups);
echo current($groups); //the last one
```

If you wanna have the last/first *key* then just do something like `$tmp = array_keys($groups);` .

Comment: of course, I can just do $groupNames = array_keys($groups), then I have $groupNames[0] and $groupNames[1], thanks.

Comment: @Edward yeah, I was searching too far about this.

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = array('Alpha' => 1.1,'Bravo' => 2.2,'Charlie' => 3.3,'Delta' => 4.4,'Echo' =>5.5, 'Golf' => 6.6);

$pos = 3;

function getAtPos($tmpArray,$pos) {
 return array_splice($tmpArray,$pos-1,1);
}

$return = getAtPos($array,$pos);

var_dump($return);
```

OR

```
$array = array('Alpha' => 1.1,'Bravo' => 2.2,'Charlie' => 3.3,'Delta' => 4.4,'Echo' =>5.5, 'Golf' => 6.6);

$pos = 3;

function getAtPos($tmpArray,$pos) {
    $keys = array_keys($tmpArray);
    return array($keys[$pos-1] => $tmpArray[$keys[$pos-1]]);
}

$return = getAtPos($array,$pos);

var_dump($return);
```

**EDIT**

Assumes $pos = 1 for the first element, but easy to change for $pos = 0 by changing the $pos-1 references in the functions to $pos

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_keys, depending on how big your array is.

```
echo $groups[( array_keys( $groups )[1] )];
```