# Get specific element of associative array by position without loop

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Is there any function which can return, for example, the 3rd element of an associative array without any loop? (and without copying the array)

I know that I can do a for/foreach loop together with a counter, but I'm just curious.

---

PS: I already found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4050021/5165343), but I was expecting something from php which would do something like getAssociativeDataByIndex($array, $index) for example.

EDIT: content of this post:

> ```
> function getAtPos($tmpArray,$pos) {
>  return array_splice($tmpArray,$pos-1,1);
> }
>
> $array = array('Alpha' => 1.1,'Bravo' => 2.2,'Charlie' => 3.3,'Delta' => 4.4,'Echo' =>5.5, 'Golf' => 6.6);    
> $pos = 3;
>
> $return = getAtPos($array,$pos);    
> var_dump($return); // 3.3
> ```

---

PS2: I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15094025/5165343), but the ArrayIterator class and the seek method is not (well) documented, so I'm not if this create a copy of the array or not (if it does, I do not think it's interesting)

EDIT: content of this post:

> ```
> $keys = array_keys($array);
> echo $array[$keys[$position]];
>
> OR 
>
> The ArrayIterator class can also do this for you:
>
> $iterator = new ArrayIterator($array);
> $iterator->seek($position);
> ```

---

example of array:

```
$a = array('jean' => 3, 'simon' => 2, 'alex' => 5, 'derek' => 4);
```

*Example of use case:
you have an external library which takes an array in parameter, process it and return you an array like index=>boolean (or index=>data)*

*e.g.: array(1=>false, 2=>false, 3=>true)...*

Answer (score 1):

[array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) will basically convert your associative array to a numeric array while maintaining the order:

```
<?php
$a = array('jean' => 3, 'simon' => 2, 'alex' => 5, 'derek' => 4);
$values = array_values($a);
print_r($values);
?>
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 4
)
```

Comment: Thanks! yes I saw this option from the first link...but array_values seems to be "relatively expensive"